# best way to define instance variables in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am using below way to define instance variables in objective-c:

```
@interface LITransactionTableViewController ()<LIServiceDelegate,LIPopUpViewDelegate>{
    NSMutableArray *alltransactions;
    LIGetUnknownTransactionService *getUnknownTransactionService;
    LIActivityView *activityview;
    TransactionLog *selectedtran;
    CALayer *backlayer;
    NSInteger selectedRow;
}
```

now what is the best way to define variables like this in the swift?

Comment: are you asking how to define class variable in swift vs instance variable?

Comment: The Objective-C code you posted defines instance variables. There is no such thing as class variables in Objective-C.

Comment: your question is ambiguous. Are you trying to define class variables or instance variables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you show is not called *class* variable, it is called *instance* variable in Objective-C.

In order to create "instance" variable in Swift you can just declare variable like this:

```
let backLayer = CALayer()
```

However, I would recommend to add **private** in front of *var* or *let*, so it will not be accessed outside the class - same as instance variable in Objective-C:

```
private let backLayer = CALayer()
private var selectedRow: Int = 0
```

Computed class variable can be defined like this:

```
class var pi: Double { return 3.14 }
```

I would recommend to use **class** vars only if you want to override it in a subclass, otherwise you can use:

```
static let pi = 3.14
```

Comment: Yes, it does not have to be private, but in ObjC instance variables are not accessibly from any other class, so I would recommend to add _private_ in front of variable in Swift to make it behave the same way. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: In general in order to preserve encapsulation in Swift unless variables and methods are specifically designed to be accessible from outside the class it is best mark them `private`.

Comment: He asked how to define class method and in example he showed instance variable, is not he?

Comment: @EricD. Corrected my response. Let me know if something is wrong.

Comment: The "class variable" in the answer is actually a "computed class property".

Comment: @EricD. yes, my mistake, did not initially provide enough description about _private_ and that it is not what _defines_ an instance var. Thank you.

Comment: @zaph in question I still can see "I am using below way to define class variables in objective-c: ... now what is the best way to define variables like this in the swift?". I think my answer shows how to define both - _class_ vars and _instance_ vars.

Comment: Almost but I guess correctness is not that important.

Comment: A bit off-topic but use the provided constant `M_PI` for *pi*.